# I am trying to create an ECS service in cloudformation, and I want to use the default VPC that it creates, and choose any of the subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

Below is the yaml template. In the NetworkConfiguration, the subnet property is required. How should I set it to be any subnet of the default VPC that was created?

```
Resources:
    ECSService:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Service
        Properties:
            TaskDefinition: !Ref ECSTaskDefinition
            LaunchType: FARGATE
            Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
            ServiceName: !Join
                - '-'
                - 
                    - !Ref Message
                    - !Ref Stage
                    - service
            DesiredCount: 1
            DeploymentConfiguration:
                MaximumPercent: 200
                MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
            NetworkConfiguration:
                AwsvpcConfiguration:
                    AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
                    Subnets: 
                        - ?????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t a value for “any subnet in this vpc”, you’d have to set the subnets in the template or as a parameter.

Alternatively you can create the vpc and subnets in the template and reference them when describing your ECS service.

Lastly you could use a custom resource to call a Lambda function that looks up the subnets but it’s more complicated than a native reference. See an AWS blog post on it here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/looking-up-information-on-aws-cloudformation-stack-parameters-using-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 0):

If it is a default vpc, you could try hardcoding the values. Or defined an new vpc and subnets in your template and refer to them.

Btw you can try [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io) which is an online aws cloudformation template generator. It should make your life less dreadful while dealing with cloudformation templates. ;-)